# I got syntax error by using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

[Here the image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzyXX.png)I dont know why i get this error.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

data = pd.read_csv("files/ch04/ACCIDENTS_GU_BCN_2013.csv" , encoding= 'unicode_escape')
data['Date'] = data[u'Dia de mes']. apply(lambda x: str(x))
+ '-' + data[u'Mes de any']. apply(lambda x: str(x))
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
accidents = data.groupby (['Date']).size()
print accidents.mean()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem here is that you're using Python3 which requires brackets after the print statement.
So, do this : **print(accidents.mean())**

Answer (score 0):

looking at the tags of your question:

```
if python==3 then print(arg)
```